# How to set C++ model throug parent components in qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have:

1. a c++ model class (*Bank*) for storing simple data objects (*Coefficient*):

```
typedef quint32 Coefficient;

class Bank : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<Coefficient> coefficients READ coefficients WRITE setCoefficients NOTIFY coefficientsChanged)

public:
    explicit Bank(QList<Coefficient> coefficients = QList<Coefficient>(), QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QList<Coefficient> coefficients() const;
    void setCoefficients(QList<Coefficient> coefficients);

    // ...

signals:
    void coefficientsChanged(QList<Coefficient> coefficients);

private:
    QList<Coefficient> _coefficients;
};
```

2. an AbstractListModel class (*BankClass*) for working with data throug views:

```
class Bank;

class BankModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Bank* bank READ bank WRITE setBank)

public:
    enum {
        CoefficientRole = Qt::UserRole
    };

    explicit BankModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = CoefficientRole) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole) override;

    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const override;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;

    Bank* bank() const;
    void setBank(Bank* bank);

private:
    Bank* _bank;
};
```

3. a QObjectList-based model to store several AbstractListModel's (*BankModel*'s)

```
class CoefficientListModel;

class ConfigModel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject*> banks READ banks WRITE setBanks NOTIFY banksChanged)

public:
    explicit ConfigModel(QList<QObject*> banks = QList<QObject*>(), QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QList<QObject*> banks() const;
    void setBanks(QList<QObject*> banks);

signals:
    void banksChanged(QList<QObject*> banks);

private:
    QList<QObject*> _banks;
};
```

4. and a qml view to set it all up (main.qml):

```
Window {
    // ...
    ListView {
        // ...
        model: cfg // ConfigModel
        delegate: ConfigDelegate {
            // ...
            ListView {
                model: model.bank // BankModel
                delegate: BankDelegate {
                    some int property: coefficient // my role in bank model
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where cfg is a registered in *main.cpp* object:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<CoefficientListModel>("Config", 1, 0, "CoefficientListModel");
    qmlRegisterType<ConfigModel>("Config", 1, 0, "ConfigModel");

    ConfigModel cfg;
    cfg.setBanks(QList<QObject*>()
                 << new CoefficientListModel(QList<Coefficient>({ Coefficient { 11 }, Coefficient { 21 }, Coefficient { 31 }, Coefficient { 41 } }))
                 // ...
                 << new CoefficientListModel(QList<Coefficient>({ Coefficient { 15 }, Coefficient { 25 }, Coefficient { 35 }, Coefficient { 45 } }))
                 );

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("cfg"), &cfg);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("client"), &client);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

So, how to set c++ models in this qml depth from upper level?
Or what's wrong here? Is it right application architecture?

It should looks like in the picture below.
[image]

**Edit:**

Now I've got a class as a tree item:

```
class CoefficientItem
{
public:
    CoefficientItem(quint32 value = -1, int row = 0, CoefficientItem* parent = nullptr);
    ~CoefficientItem();

    CoefficientItem *childAt(int i);
    int childrenCount();
    CoefficientItem *parent();
    quint32 value() const;
    int row() const;

    void setValue(const quint32& value);
    void setParent(CoefficientItem* parent_item);

    void appendChild(CoefficientItem* child);

private:
    quint32 _value;
    CoefficientItem* _parent_item;
    QHash<int, CoefficientItem*> _child_items;
    int _row_number;
};
```

and tree model:

```
class ConfigModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    enum { CoefficientRole = Qt::UserRole };

public:
    explicit ConfigModel(const QVector<QVector<quint32>>& config, CoefficientItem* root = nullptr, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~ConfigModel();

    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &index) const override;

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = CoefficientRole) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole) override;

    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const override;

    void setModelUp(const QVector<QVector<quint32> >& config);

private:
    CoefficientItem* _root_item;
};
```

And the problem now is in access to internal level of tree model. In *main.qml* i have a list view:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: DelegateModel {
        model: cfg
        delegate: BankView {}
    }
}
```

*BankView.qml* is the delegate which consists of *BankViewHeader.qml* (as a checkbox) and *BankViewDescription.qml* (as a Component with List of TextFields)

*BankView.qml*:

```
Rectangle {
    id: bank_view
    width: parent.width
    height: bank_view_column.height
    color: "#946782"

    Column {
        id: bank_view_column
        spacing: 0
        clip: true

        BankViewHeader {
            id: checker
            text: qsTr("Bank " + model.index)
            checked: true
            implicitWidth: bank_view.width
        }

        BankViewDescription {
            id: description
            isOpened: checker.checked
            width: bank_view.width
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: checker.checked = false
}
```

*BankViewDescription.qml*:

```
RowLayout {
    // ...
    ListView {
        model: DelegateModel {
            model: model // <-- problem here ???
            delegate: Row {
                TextField {
                    //... use my role here - coefficient (uint32)
                }
            }
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

So what's wrong? no any errors in log, and top level of tree works fine (i think), view shows 4 banks as were initialized in *main.cpp*.

[image]

Comment: I think you should use QList<QObject*> (where QObject is actually a Bank) to have a list of all your Bank's, that way you don't have to specify a indexed property on your root Context for every bank you ever want to make

Comment: and how i will get access to every coefficient in qml?

Comment: As QML doesn't (yet maybe) understand QVector I would make a QList property on the `Bank` class. And you can actually use typedef instead of struct with one member, unless you are planning to have more members, then you could consider using `Q_GADGET`

Comment: Look, for example.
I have:
**1.** (Coefficient) a complex object model (not only int value as a field);
**2.** (Bank) a c++ model for storing several objects (with Q_PROPERTY for container of objects);
**3.** (BankModel) an AbstractListModel for edit data and work throug qml view;
**4.** (ConfigModel) a QObjectList-based model for storing several (BankModel's) AbstracktListModel's.
**5.** Register config model object as ConfigModel in main.cpp and set it at model field in ListView in main.qml.
Is it right application architecture yet?

Comment: so, you want the AbstractListModel to have multiple hierachical levels? You should use QAbstractItemModel and implement the virtual functions (takes a bit of effort, I know), then in QML you can use a `DelegateModel` and use the `rootIndex` (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html) )

Comment: Yes, smth like that i think. I will try, and thanks for your help

Comment: Hey, next problem. Check edit part please

Comment: great progress :-) you should set the `rootIndex` property in BankViewDescription.qml, probably easiest to set it through a aliased property (on RowLayout) to `cfg.index(index, 0)` (where the first "index" is the function on the abstractItemModel and the second "index" is the row number, automatically created by ListView)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209843/discussion-between---and-amfasis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, consider to EDIT part and with Amfasis help the solution is:
for that structure (2d data storage like on the picture at question) we should make a tree model, and after that we should set our qml correct structure.

The qml structure in my case:

```
// model view in main.qml
ListView {
    // ...
    model: DelegateModel {
        id: bank_list_model
        model: cfg // my ConfigModel
        delegate: BankView {
            bankIndex: bank_list_model.modelIndex(index)
        }
    }
}
```

BankView.qml:

```
Rectangle {  // your any item
    property alias bankIndex: description.bankIndex

    // ...

    BankViewDescription {
        id: description
        // ...
    } 
}
```

BankViewDescription.qml:

```
RowLayout {  // your any item
    property alias bankIndex: regs_list_model.rootIndex

    // ...

    ListView {
        model: DelegateModel {
            id: regs_list_model
            model: cfg
            delegate: Row {
                TextField {
                    text: coefficient // use your role
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So here we link DelegateModel rootIndex property throug our items with aliases.

PS: I forgot to override roleNames method on ConfigModel at edit part.

PPS: If you know a more simple way to describe a model-view connection or app structure, you are welcome.